# Build Dynamic SQL with Joins on multiple keys

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to build a dynamic query where all the data points are stored in a table.

e.g.

```
Declare @Load varchar(2000) = 'Id,CategoryID,SubcatID'
```

I need the below output:

```
 on b.id = b2.id and b.CategoryID = b2.CategoryID and b.SubcatID = b2.SubcatID 
 where b.id is null and b.CategoryID is null and b.SubcatID is null
```

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need a delimiter split function. What version of SQL? Some versions have one built in

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the task

Thanks

```
SELECT *
, 'b.'+Value Sources 
, 'b2.'+Value Destination 
, 'b.'+Value +'='+ 'b2.'+Value JoinCondition
, 'b2.'+Value + ' IS NULL ' JoinFilters
into #temp
FROM dbo.Split(@IncrementalLoad,',')
    
    
SELECT STRING_AGG(JoinCondition, ' and ') AS JoinCondition 
, STRING_AGG(JoinFilters, ' and ') AS JoinFilters
from #temp
```